# Proof of orthonormality of Haar System (book is wrong)?

Tags: proof-explanation, orthonormal

[image]

So the arguments in (2), (3), it says $h_{j',k'}(x)$ is identically 1 or -1. That's not true is it? since we can't assume $j,j' \in \mathbb Z$ are 0, and the proof is incorrectly assuming the arbitrary haar function has "height" of 1 when it can be dilated?

Comment: "it says $h_{j',k'}(x)$ is identically 1 or -1" it says only that it says $h_{j',k'}(x)$ is identically 1 or -1 _on_ a certain interval. I gather that that's not the problem, you're concerned that the $\pm1$ is wrong. Of course this doesn't matter, it _is_ $\pm c_j$. About whether it's right: What was the definition of $h_{j,k}$?

Comment: $h_{j,k} $ is the Haar system function. Let $h(x) = \chi_{[0,\frac{1}{2})}(x) - \chi_{[\frac{1}{2}, 1)}(x)$. Then for each $j,k \in \mathbb Z$, define $h_{j,k}(x) = 2^{j/2} h(2^j x - k) = D_{2^j}T_x (x)$, where D is the dilation operator, T is the translation operator. So the Haar system function $h_{j,k}$ can simply be though of as taking a square "sinusoid" of height 1, -1 on left and right half of interval $[0,1)$ respectively, and dilating and translating it. Because proof assumes arbitrary j, the function will be arbitrarily dilated and we can't assume height is 1 or -1 if $j \neq 0$

Comment: With that definition yes, the proof exactly as stated is wrong. Of course it really amounts to just a typo, since you can fix it just by changing $\pm 1$ to $\pm 2^{j/2}$ (or $2^{j'/2}$ or whatever).

Comment: right ok, just making sure I"m not misunderstanding something. This textbook's proofs has had several minor mistakes so far..